# Solr Core Initialization Failures

Tags: solr

Trying to configure Solr 7.2.1 with Sitecore 8.2

But after generating `schema.xml` with Sitecore when i am trying to add core from Solr Admin Page, i am getting below error.

Please have a look at attached screenshot.

[image]

Any expert advice?

Comment: Actually Solr 7.2.1 is not supported by Sitecore 8.2. Check the Solr compatibility table: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897

Comment: Thanks Artesem actually i was little bit confused about the compatibility.

https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897

So do we have to revert and start configuring on solr previous verision like solr-6.6.2?

Thanks again

Comment: Sitecore 8.2 supports Solr 6.0 – 6.1.
Solr 6.6.1 is not supported. I think the same with 6.6.2.
So, download the Solr 6.1 and go through the solution 2 in the article.

Comment: I am using solr 6.6.2 with sitecore 8.2 update 6 and its working fine, so you can also try with solr 6.6.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always advisable to follow the compatibility table but if you still wants to use the installed version then please check below line is exist in your schema.xml or not?

`<field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

Answer (score 2):

Unsupported Solr version. Please see the compatibility table https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897. Sitecore relies on Solr definition field *version*, which is not present at your new generated schema.xml, therefore you are getting this Solr error, you can try adding this field into the schema and try again, or downgrade the Solr to the compatible listed version in the link I've provided.